# How to return result from include model in same level of main model in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

This is the code and result that I have done in my project.
I would like to get the result of include model in the same result with the main model. the below code is what I have done.

Sequelize query:

```
 User.findAll({
        include: [{
                model: Position,
                attributes: ['POSITION_NAME'],
            }
        ]
    }).then(user => {
        res.json({
            data: user
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

result that I get

```
     [
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "NAME": "AAA",
            "LAST_NAME": "BBB",
            "Position": {
                "POSITION_NAME": "ວິຊາການສັນຍາຈ້າງ"
            }
        }
]
```

result that I want:

```
     [
        {
            
        "ID": 2,
        "NAME": "AAA",
        "LAST_NAME": "BBB",
        "POSITION_NAME": "ວິຊາການສັນຍາຈ້າງ"
        }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this .

```
User.findAll({
    attributes: ["ID", "NAME", ["Position.POSITION_NAME", "POSITION_NAME"]],
    include: [{
        model: Position,
        attributes: [],
    }
    ],
    raw:true
}).then(user => {
    res.json({
        data: user
    })
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: Thanks,but there was an error occurred.


  original: Error: Unknown column 'Position.POSITION_NAME' in 'field list'

Comment: i have updated my code try it. if it still not work than please share your schema .

Comment: Wow, after I set raw: true. The output is as I want :). Thank you so much @Vyas Arpit

Comment: with my pleasure :)

Comment: Worked well except, `attributes: ["ID", "NAME", "Position.POSITION_NAME", "POSITION_NAME"],`