# how to return values from joined tables in sequelize at the same level as master table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to find a way how to put all joined tables at the same level as my master table... so far it only results in the nested values in my final object ..

Here is what I have

```
Orders.findAll({
   include: [
      {model: Products, attributes: ['product_name']}
   ],
   attributes: ['id_order', 'dtime_order', 'amount']
})
```

what I am getting is:

```
[
 {
   id_order: 1, 
   dtime_order: '2021-05-24T22:00:00.000Z',
   amount: 20,
   products: {
      product_name: 'Picture'
   }
 }
]
```

but what I wanna get is:

```
[
 {
   id_order: 1, 
   dtime_order: '2021-05-24T22:00:00.000Z',
   amount: 20,
   product_name: 'Picture'
 }
]
```

I tried this [How to return result from include model in same level of main model in Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507000/how-to-return-result-from-include-model-in-same-level-of-main-model-in-sequelize) but unfortunately when I did:

```
Orders.findAll({
   include: [
      {model: Products, attributes: []}
   ],
   attributes: ['id_order', 'dtime_order', 'amount', ['products.product_name', 'product_name']]
})
```

doesn't work for me saying

```
column "products.product_name" does not exist
```

There might be a hacky way to modify the object before sending it back in the response .. but I would rather do it within Sequelize ..

any idea is very welcome... thank you guys!

EDIT: adding the generated SQL

```
Executing (default): SELECT "orders"."id_order", "orders"."dtime_order", "orders"."amount", "products.product_name", FROM "orders" AS "orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" AS "products" ON "orders"."id_order" = "products"."ir_order";
error:   Get dashboard data error: column "products.product_name" does not exist
```

**SOLUTION:**

I had to use an alias in my association

`Orders.hasOne(Products, {as: 'products', ....})`

And then use that EXACTLY SAME alias in my include and referencing

`include: [{model: Products, attributes: [], as: 'products'}]`

And

`attributes: [ ... , [Sequelize.col('products.product_name', 'product_name')]`

without the `raw: true` works like a charm :) Thank you @Emma !!!

Comment: You are missing `raw: true`.  Also perhaps, `products.product_name` (lower case p). You can find what table name exactly in generated SQL.

Comment: I tried `raw: true` but it doesn't work.. .and yes, the lowercase doesn't work either.. on top of that, what's the point of Sequelize if I have to "hardcode" the table name directly.. where is the abstraction then?

Comment: What is the generated SQL?   Also *most* of the cases, you use model instance and don't have to hardcode, this is one of the special case.

Comment: Could you also try `[Sequelize.col('products.product_name'), 'product_name']`?  In some version, I needed to have `Sequelize.col`.

Comment: I added the SQL query I am getting .... there is a weird part about the quotes - it does not quote the table name and column separately but as one string .. that might be the problem

Comment: oh yes cool...  I thought I tried that  `Sequelize.col` before but obviously I didn't :) it works great ... thx a lot .. pls use it as an answer so I can tag it properly !! thx a lot

Comment: Nice!  Glad it worked.

Comment: oh I see why it didn't worked before.. I had to use an alias to the table ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use `Sequelize.col` to wrap the nested column so that Sequelize can properly alias the column.

```
Orders.findAll({
  include: [
    {model: Products, attributes: []}
  ],
  attributes: ['id_order', 'dtime_order', 'amount', [Sequelize.col('products.product_name'), 'product_name']],
  raw: true
})
```

Comment: I had to use an alias (esp to avoid directly addressing the table name) and `raw: true` is not needed in my case .. but tagging this as a good answer because of `Sequelize.col()`